# Bun dev command stop working automatically

Tags: javascript, crash, debian, bun

I've installed bun on a debian running with WSL2 and created a React project.

So far I've tried to run "bun dev" command but it always stop automatically after 2-3 seconds with no error.

I've searched but still don't found why it's making this.
I've also tried an next.js app and it do the same.

Comment: exactly same here. Do you have any progress?